# How to colour decision regions in k-means?

Tags: matlab, k-means

I am just starting out on doing k-means clustering in MATLAB. I have a 10x10 matrix `X`, whose values I want to group into 3 clusters. This is my code:

```
[idx,C] = kmeans(X,3);
x1 = min(X(:,1)):0.01:max(X(:,1));
x2 = min(X(:,2)):0.01:max(X(:,2));
[x1G,x2G] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
XGrid = [x1G(:),x2G(:)]; % Defines a fine grid on the plot

idx2Region = kmeans(XGrid,3,'MaxIter',5,'dist','sqeuclidean');

figure;
gscatter(XGrid(:,1),XGrid(:,2),idx2Region,...
    [0,0.75,0.75;0.75,0,0.75;0.75,0.75,0],'..');
hold on;
plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'k*','MarkerSize',5);
xlabel 'Petal Lengths (cm)';
ylabel 'Petal Widths (cm)';
legend('Region 1','Region 2','Region 3','Data','Location','Best','NE');
hold off;
```

But I get the decision regions with coloured dots (shown in the figure attached). How do I make the colour continuous?[image]

Comment: what do you mean by continuous? Like a smooth transition between each region?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I mean the regions should be solid pink, solid yellow, and solid blue. Unlike what we have here, which is dotted pink, dotted yellow, and dotted blue. In other words, I don't want any white space in my plot.